# Event times in different reference frames in the context of Special Relativity

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames

I'm having a bit of difficulty puzzling out the correct way to move between frames in the context of a basic Special Relativity problem.

The problem basically states that two bodies ($A$ and $B$) are moving apart at a relative velocity $v$ (and we are assuming only 1-spacial dimension for simplicity), and body $A$ emits a light-pulse at time $t_{\alpha}$ which body $B$ receives at time $t_{\beta}$, and I am asked to simply show that in $A$'s reference frame:

$$t_{\beta} = \frac{t_{\alpha}}{1-\frac{v}{c}}$$

In the initial reference frame of $B$, we observe that $t_{\alpha}^{\prime}=\gamma t_{\alpha}$ and that the light-pulse is emitted at a distance $v\gamma t_{\alpha}$ from $B$, so we receive the light-pulse at:

$$t_{\beta}^{\prime} = \gamma t_{\alpha} + \frac{v\gamma t_{\alpha}}{c}$$

But in the initial reference frame of $A$, we have $t_{\beta} = \frac{1}{\gamma}t_{\beta}^{\prime}$, so:

$$t_{\beta} = t_{\alpha}\left(1+\frac{v}{c}\right)$$

Which is not equal to the expression I was asked to show, so what have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{equation}
t_{\beta}^{\prime} = \gamma t_{\alpha} + \frac{v\gamma t_{\alpha}}{c}
\tag{01}
\end{equation}
Your equation (01) is right, but your equation (02) is wrong :

\begin{equation}
t_{\beta} \ne \frac{1}{\gamma}t_{\beta}^{\prime}
\tag{02}
\end{equation}

The right (02) equation is :

\begin{equation}
t_{\beta} =\gamma t_{\beta}^{\prime}
\tag{02$^{\prime}$}
\end{equation}
So, multiplying (01) by $\gamma$ yields
\begin{equation}
t_{\beta} = \gamma^{2}\left( 1 + \frac{v}{c}\right)t_{\alpha}=\dfrac{\left( 1 + \frac{v}{c}\right)}{\left(1 -\frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)}t_{\alpha}=\dfrac{1}{1-\frac{v}{c}}t_{\alpha}
\tag{03}
\end{equation}

When two events happen **at the same point**, $\Delta x = 0 $, at $\Delta t$ time apart in the unprimed system (here **A**) then in the primed system (here **B**) happen at time apart

\begin{equation}
\Delta t^{\prime}=\gamma\left(\Delta t-\frac{v \Delta x}{c^2}\right)
\tag{04}
\end{equation}
that is
\begin{equation}
\Delta t^{\prime}=\gamma\Delta t
\tag{05}
\end{equation}

So, suppose that the two systems **A** and **B** start at the same space point with $x=0, t=0$ for **A** and $x^{\prime}=0,t^{\prime}=0$  for **B**.  System  **B** is moving with speed $v$ towards the positive $x$ of  **A** .

We  have two events in **A** :

Event  $\sigma $   :  Observer A has observer B on  $x_{\sigma}=0$ at $t_{\sigma}=0$.

Event  $ \alpha $  :  Observer A from $x_{\alpha}=0$ at $t=t_{\alpha}$ sends a light-pulse to  B.

We have 
\begin{equation}
\Delta x = x_{\alpha}-x_{\sigma}=0  , \qquad  \Delta t = t_{\alpha}-t_{\sigma}=t_{\alpha}
\tag{06}
\end{equation}

So from (05)
\begin{equation}
\Delta t^{\prime} = t_{\alpha}^{\prime}-t_{\sigma}^{\prime}=\gamma \Delta t =\gamma \left(t_{\alpha}-t_{\sigma}\right)
\tag{07}
\end{equation}

that is
\begin{equation}
 t_{\alpha}^{\prime}=\gamma t_{\alpha}
\tag{08}
\end{equation}

That's all right till now.

Now let the following two events in  **B** :

Event  $\sigma $   :  Observer B has observer A on  $x_{\sigma}^{\prime}=0$ at $t_{\sigma}^{\prime}=0$.

Event  $ \beta $     :  Observer B receives on $x_{\beta}^{\prime}=0$ at $t=t_{\beta}^{\prime}$ the light-pulse from A.

We have 
\begin{equation}
\Delta x ^{\prime}= x_{\beta}^{\prime}-x_{\sigma}^{\prime}=0  , \qquad  \Delta t ^{\prime}= t_{\beta}^{\prime}-t_{\sigma}^{\prime}= t_{\beta}^{\prime}
\tag{09}
\end{equation}

Of course here we have for the inverse Lorentz transformation

\begin{equation}
\Delta t=\gamma\left(\Delta t ^{\prime}+\frac{v \Delta x^{\prime}}{c^2}\right)
\tag{10}
\end{equation}

So,
\begin{equation}
\Delta t = t_{\beta}-t_{\sigma}=\gamma \Delta t ^{\prime}= \gamma \left( t_{\beta}^{\prime}-t_{\sigma}^{\prime}\right)= \gamma t_{\beta}^{\prime}
\tag{11}
\end{equation}

and finally

\begin{equation}
t_{\beta} =\gamma t_{\beta}^{\prime}
\tag{02$^{\prime}$}
\end{equation}

---

When two events happen **at the same point** of an unprimed system (here **A**) then in the primed system (here **B**)
\begin{equation}
\Delta t^{\prime}=\gamma\Delta t
\tag{05}
\end{equation}

---

When two events happen **at the same point** of an primed system (here **B**) then in the unprimed system (here **A**)

\begin{equation}
\Delta t=\gamma\Delta t^{\prime}
\tag{12}
\end{equation}